# How to display the zone name in a rails time_zone_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, timezone

I am trying to add a select input field that sets priority us zones and displays the the time as "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" instead of "(GMT - 05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"

If I use the following time_zone_select, I get the us time zones followed by the remaining time zones as I desire, but each zone uses the "(GMT ... " formatting that I would prefer not to use.

```
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones %>
```

If I use the following collection_select, I get the zones using my preferred format "Eastern Time (US & Canada)", but only the US Zones and nothing else.

```
<%= f.collection_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, :name, :name %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the second way is appropriate then you can use `all` method instead of `us_zones`:

```
<%= f.collection_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all, :name, :name %>
```

Comment: This displays all of the time zones in the desired format, but it doesn't prioritize the us zones like the time_zone_select option.